# How to run a sparql when information are in different ModelRDB?

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology, dbpedia

I am working in DBPedia. i want to run some sparql. so i downloaded files from here: http://wiki.dbpedia.org/services-resources/ontology.

As you see, DBpedia seperated its triples into different files. A file for **rdf:type properties** and another file for **others properties**.

I import each file into MySQL (Persist a model); Condsider i named models "A" and "B" in order! the code is below:

for **DBpedia Ontology RDF type statements**

```
 private Model AModel;
 private Model BModel;

 DBConnection connection = new DBConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_TYPE);
 AModel = maker.createModel("A",true);
 model.begin();
 InputStream in =this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("some address /instance_types_en.nt);
 model.read(in,null);// Commit the database transactionmodel.commit();

------------
```

and again for **DBpedia Ontology other A-Box properties**

```
DBConnection connection = new DBConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_TYPE);
BModel = maker.createModel("B",true);
model.begin();
InputStream in =this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("some address /mappingbased_properties_en.nt);
model.read(in,null);// Commit the database transactionmodel.commit();
```

so till here, we have two models, ones **for DBpedia Ontology RDF type statements**
and **another for DBpedia Ontology other A-Box properties**.

The problen is where we have a sparql that need both  inforamtion. (rdf:type properties and non rdf:type prpperties); such as:

**Who was the wife of President Lincoln?**

its equivalence sparql is:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?uri ?string
WHERE 
{
    ?person rdf:type onto:President .
    ?person foaf:surname "Lincoln"@en .
    ?person onto:spouse ?uri.
        OPTIONAL {?uri rdfs:label ?string .}
        FILTER (lang(?string) = "en") 
}
```

so i should run this sparql in models. but jena just let me to perform sparql in just one model:

so i have to run it like:

```
QueryExecution qe1 = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, AModel));
```

or

```
QueryExecution qe1 = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, BModel));
```

**

> ?person onto:spouse ?uri. 
>   is in **AModel** and 
>   ?person rdf:type onto:Presiden 
>   is in **BModel**!

So this query returns no record!

so what is the solution. my program generate the right sparql but i do not have the appropriate data set to return the response!
 Because i have different models, so i can not use Union operator here!!

Comment: Your code seems to be missing come imporrant aspects - how does "connection" relate to AModel or model? Now do AModel and model relate? The RDB databse solution is very old and the version of jena it depends on is unlikely to work with SPARQL very well.

Comment: Real Codes work well. It's just pseudo code. (To explain problem space... .)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches:

1. Read all the data into the same model
2. Use a union model (ModelFactory.createUnion or MultiUnion).
3. Read the models separately into a RDF dataset (not possible with RDB).
4. Create a Dataset which has both models separately in it.

If you are using a version of Jena which has DBConnection, some of these may not work as the code is so old.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is here that i've big files (about 4 gig); so the solution led me to use RDB. Let me ask a question, are there any suggestion for handling big rdf files?

Comment: As you mentioned, none of above appriaches are  consistent with this jena version!

Comment: What version are you using? Upgrade and use TDB.